# Loopback application middleware not working - No matching layer found errors

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, loopback

I have integrated my loopback application with appDynamics library and all the middlewares are not firing from then on.
Used the debug command - DEBUG=* npm start to get the logs and found these logs coming up.

All the middlewares declared through middleware.json and imperatively through app.middleware() command are having this error message - **No matching layer found**

Any idea what's going wrong here - Which loopback package is responsible for express routing implementation

````
2020-07-10T15:23:11.241Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:boot:executor Configuring middleware "/usr/nodejs/njsDT_SIT/apps/wlpn/ob-cof-funds-confirmation-consents-channel/package/node_modules/compression" 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.243Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:app use initial compression 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.244Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT express:router use [] compression 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.245Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT express:router:layer new [] 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.245Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:app No matching layer is found for initial compression 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.245Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:boot:executor Configuring middleware "/usr/nodejs/njsDT_SIT/apps/wlpn/ob-cof-funds-confirmation-consents-channel/package/node_modules/loopback-context/server/middleware/per-request.js" 2020-07-10T15:23:11.246Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:app use initial perRequestContext 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.253Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT express:router use [] perRequestContext 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.254Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT express:router:layer new [] 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.254Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:app No matching layer is found for initial perRequestContext 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.254Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:boot:executor Configuring middleware "/usr/nodejs/njsDT_SIT/apps/wlpn/ob-cof-funds-confirmation-consents-channel/package/node_modules/cors" 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.254Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:app use initial corsMiddleware 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.254Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT express:router use [] corsMiddleware 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.254Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT express:router:layer new [] 
2020-07-10T15:23:11.254Z - : pid:36871 worker:1 Fri, 10 Jul 2020 15:23:11 GMT loopback:app No matching layer is found for initial corsMiddleware```
````